# No item error in Pandas when the item is certainly there

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (BenchmarkData) in Python 3.3 indexed with every day from 1996 through 2013.  Typically, I will access data using a string:

```
BenchmarkData['2007-11-01']
```

However, I am now getting a 'no item named 2007-11-01' error.  However, if I try:

```
BenchmarkData['2007-10-30':'2007-11-3']
```

I can see the value clearly, and indeed even this works:

```
BenchmarkData['2007-11-01':'2007-11-01']
```

This issue is not unique to the date 2007-11-01, but seems true for all dates.  Why can't I access this value using the string, as I have done in the past?

Comment: what version of pandas?

Comment: see docs related to this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing, IIRC this has not been changed as far back as I recal.

Comment: I am using Pandas 0.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also the indexing methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics. 
When indexing a DataFrame:

- a single label (`df[label]`) selects a column
- a slice (`df[start:stop]`) slices the rows

In your case, `BenchmarkData['2007-11-01':'2007-11-01']` slices the rows, so this is OK, but `BenchmarkData['2007-11-01']` tries to access a column names '2007-11-01' which does not exist.

Use `df.loc[label]` to select a single row from a DataFrame.

Comment: Yes!  I had been accessing it with just a string before because this variable had been a TimeSeries.  As a DataFrame, it would look for a column rather than the key.